# Aggregation Framework & large number of queries

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have next document structure and insertion rules.
Document : `{_id : 1, priority : 1.89, etc...}`.
Rules : the field priority should be unique, the insert operation must affect the smallest number of elements.

I want to calculate new priority(Priority that will be displayed for user, 1,2,3,etc..) on db level.In SQL i can execute the next query(Based on Subquery)

```
Select *, (Select Count(fldName) from tableName where priority <= tn.priority) as priority from tableName as tn
```

In documentation i didn't found information about something similar, $project, $group, $let, etc...

Could you please give me advice about my problem!)

P.S
I can't store the data in normal form, they very often change and affect many elements.
Example :

```
{_id : 1, priority : 1, etc...}
{_id : 2, priority : 2, etc...}
{_id : 3, priority : 3, etc...}

insert in the middle

{_id : 4, priority : 2, etc...}

I should switch another elements

{_id : 1, priority : 1, etc...}
{_id : 4, priority : 2, etc...}
{_id : 2, priority : 3, etc...}
{_id : 3, priority : 4, etc...}
```

Comment: I feel there is something wrong in your design, that it forces you to do such calculations. Anyway, let's assume you have to do it, so please confirm: do you want to update priorities of all documents with this field greater than or equal to the priority coming with the new document?

Comment: Yeah, you are right. All documents that have priority greater than new document shall be moved)